# Mercurial Textmate bundle broken after switch to 1.5.10

Tags: textmate, mercurial

After I left Textmate 1.5.9 for 1.5.10 the Textmate Mercurial bundle didn't find `hg` anymore.

Probably due to this change:

> [CHANGED] Commands (without shebang) no longer source the default shell startup files. This means that nothing in TextMate will use the value of PATH setup in ~/.profile or similar (and on the plus side, nothing in your shell startup files will trip TextMate).

I added `/usr/local/bin/` to the new Textmate PATH and `hg` was found again. Now, however, the TM bundle always gives me

> File(s) not modified; nothing to commit.

or something similar, seemingly indicating it doesn't recognize my project anymore. I can bring up my revision history though.

If I commit in the terminal, `hg` works as usual. I went through the output of echo $PATH (`/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin:/sw/bin:/sw/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin`)
but there was no `hg` except in /usr/local/bin.

What could cause this, or how could I narrow it down?